# SQL Server execute trigger within trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a scenario where I have table A

This table has a trigger on it when deleting (After Delete)

Within this trigger if I call a delete statement on table A (DELETE FROM TABLE A etc), I would think that this would cause the trigger to run again? Wouldn't it just loop forever and keep calling the trigger? It is not doing that, everything seems to be working normal but I cannot seem to figure this out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Whats the output of `select is_recursive_triggers_on from sys.databases where [name]=db_name();`?

Comment: The question you really need to ask yourself is do you really need a trigger in the first place? They are horribly overused, and often written poorly. In 20+ years I have used triggers maybe 3-4 times in a production environment and pretty sure I could find an alternative solution to nearly all of those that don't involve triggers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of recursion in SQL Server.

1. Direct
2. Indirect

Nesting/recursion of a trigger in SQL Server depends on the `server trigger recursion` and `nested triggers` configurations.

> Wouldn't it just loop forever and keep calling the trigger?

No. the maximum nesting level is 32 for SQL Server.

You can read about these configurations in below links
[server trigger recursion Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-trigger-recursion-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) and
[Configure the nested triggers Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16)

You can read more on this in action in below article

1. [Nested and Recursive Triggers in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9340/nested-and-recursive-triggers-in-sql-server/)
2. [Nested Triggers in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/nested-triggers-in-sql-server-6/)

A warning! You must ne careful using triggers especially in production environments. It may cause performance issues that may not be easy to figure out.

Hope this helps.